# Python: Want to edit image like adobe Photoshop

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I would like to decrease brightness, contrast, and offset of the image in Python like photoshop. I enhance the bar code in that image. I want to make that barcode visible by editing that image.

[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow is a place to ask questions about code you're having problems with. Please show your attempt, and the issues you're encountering.

Comment: from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance
    ...: im = Image.open("invisible.png")
    ...: enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(im)
    ...: enhanced_im = enhancer.enhance(1.8)
    ...: enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
    ...: enhanced_im = enhancer.enhance(4.0)
    ...: enhancer = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(im)
    ...: enhanced_im = enhancer.enhance(10.0)
    ...: enhanced_im.save("enhanced.sample5.png")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [histogram equalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization):

```
import cv2

# Load image as greyscale
im = cv2.imread('XD04u.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Equalise and save
res = cv2.equalizeHist(im)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', res)
```

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated! Thank you so much. I'm a beginner in image processing.

Answer (score 0):

````
import colorsys

def colorize(im, h, s, l_adjust):
    h /= 360.0
    s /= 100.0
    l_adjust /= 100.0
    if im.mode != 'L':
        im = im.convert('L')
    result = Image.new('RGB', im.size)
    pixin = im.load()
    pixout = result.load()
    for y in range(im.size[1]):
        for x in range(im.size[0]):
            l = pixin[x, y] / 255.99
            l += l_adjust
            l = min(max(l, 0.0), 1.0)
            r, g, b = colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h, l, s)
            r, g, b = int(r * 255.99), int(g * 255.99), int(b * 255.99)
            pixout[x, y] = (r, g, b)
    return result```
````